# Setting up Anaconda to use Tensorboard Profiler

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorboard

I just installed the tensorboard profiler with

```
pip install -U tensorboard_plugin_profile
```

The version is 2.3.
Tensorflow-Version 2.3
Tensorboard-Version 2.3
cudatoolkit-Version 10.1.243

When i now try to open the Profil-Tab in Tensorboard i see the Profiler-Window normaly but empty and the Error-Message:

```
DEM6561: Failed to load libcupti (is it installed and accessible?)
```

And the warning:

```
No step marker observed and hence the step time is unknown. This may happen if (1) training steps are not instrumented (e.g., if you are not using Keras) or (2) the profiling duration is shorter than the step time. For (1), you need to add step instrumentation; for (2), you may try to profile longer.
```

I think it has something to do with the enviroment-pathes- and variables but i dont know how they work with the virtuel enviroments of Anaconda. (I dont have a Cuda-Folder i can link to)

Had someone the same problem like me or any ideas what i can try?
Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that the CUPTI has been set to Path (via Environment Variables if you're using Windows), adding a path which should look like this:

```
%CUDA_PATH%\extras\CUPTI\lib64
```

Second, check if Tensorflow is looking for the correct CUPTI dll. I've encountered this exact same issue and as I checked, it appears that TF 2.4 is looking for cupti64_110.dll instead of cupti64_2020.1.1.dll. It is currently a [known issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43030#issuecomment-736206189) and will be addressed in TF 2.5. I'm not sure if that's the case too with TF 2.3.

I basically resolved the issue by copying the dll in the same directory and renaming it. Let me know if this helps!